# affine functions and Lipschitz continuity

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, linear-transformations, lipschitz-functions

Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ be a metric space where $||\cdot||$ is the sup-norm and let $E$ be a convex and compact subset. Let $f:E\to [0,1]$ be continuous and affine, i.e. for all $x,y\in E$ and all $\lambda \in [0,1]$, $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$.

Is $f$ Lipschitz? If not, can you give a simple counter-example?

Edit:
Technically, I can always modify the metric on $E$ such that $d(x,y)=||x-y||+|f(x)-f(y)|$. Then $f$ is Lipschitz. But this metric is not well-defined over the entire space $X$. I was hoping to show (or not show) that $f$ is Lipschitz under the original sup-norm metric.

Comment: Check the counter-example here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294868/affine-vs-lipschitz